# Recovery of deleted database from localhost in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, recovery

My database has been deleted from localhost in phpmyadmin. How can I recover my tables or database?

Is it possible to restore table to last time with data, If all data was deleted accidentally.

Answer (score 3):

No, thats not possible unless you made a backup somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yup - like Veelen mentioned the best option is a backup but if you don't have it then depending on how the deletion takes place and what kind of access to the machine you have you might also get lucky and restore the deleted files on the filesystem level... *maybe*

Even if not a full restore you might get some of the data out of the files manually - please take a look here: http://lifehacker.com/393084/how-to-recover-deleted-files-with-free-software and if you want to go this route it would be best to NOT do anything on the drive until you recover everything of decide to abandon the data.